# PayPal JavaScript SDK: Getting the Basic Card Info onApprove()

Tags: javascript, paypal

In PayPal JavaScript SDK, we get the `details` object `onApprove` as shown below:

```
onApprove: function (data, actions) {
    console.dir(data);
    // This function captures the funds from the transaction.
    return actions.order.capture()
        .then(function (details) {
            console.dir(details);
            // This function shows a transaction success message to your buyer.
            alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name);
        });
}
```

We noticed that the `details` object does not contain any information about the payment method that the payer used to make the payment, i.e. PayPal, Debit Card, or Credit Card, which of course, the **last 4 digits card number** isn't provided too.

### Why we need the Basic Card Info?

We need the basic card info to generate a more useful receipt to our customers (including corporate customers). Without such information, it's useless for our customers to keep the receipt and for their accounting purposes because they **can't even reference to which card of which bank** that they were using for the payments.

Based on the [PayPal Here docs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/paypal-here/sdk-dev/receipts/), we found this from the `Receipt API`'s response object:

```
"payment_card": {  
      "card_scheme": "CREDIT",
      "card_number": "2677", // This is what we're looking for
      "authorization_code": "087202",
      "card_soft_description": "PP*PAYDIANTPAY",
      "icc_info": {  
        "pin_present":false,
        "signature_verified":false,
        "authorization_response_code": "00",
        "authorization_response_code_label": "APPROVED",
        "icc_application_cryptogram": "606C700D55FB5C0A",
        "icc_application_cryptogram_label": "TC",
        "icc_application_identifier": "A0000000041010",
        "icc_application_PAN_number": "01",
        "terminal_id": "7688",
        "transaction_status_information": "E800",
        "issuer_application_data": "011060700222000014E100000000000000FF",
        "terminal_verification_results": "0000008000"
      }
    }
```

But how can we get the same info with the JavaScript SDK of PayPal? I've also gone through the [PayPal REST API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/) but didn't seem to find it. Please advise, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you integrate using the standard black Debit or Credit Card button, you will not receive any information about which card they used. In fact, you will not even know whether they paid with a card -- they might have fallen back to a regular PayPal checkout and used a different funding source. All billing information is kept private in PayPal by design.

If your country and currency are supported by [advanced credit and debit card payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/advanced-card-payments/) you could see about activating that for your account and integrate using that custom form (hosted fields) instead. This method *will* tell you the brand and last digits of the card in the `details` response.

Comment: Just checked, too bad that my country currency (MYR) isn't listed there. But found something here: [Order REST API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_get). Can we make a separate call after the `onApprove` just to get the `payment_source`? It should contain the card info right?

Comment: Not for standard payments, no

Comment: The bottom line is that with this integration method you should show a receipt that says that the payer paid via PayPal, and the email address used. They may have paid with a card as a PayPal guest, but it's a PayPal payment.